# perl non-greedy regex case matching too much

Tags: regex, macos, perl, html-parsing

I have a `file` with something like

```
<post href="http://example.com/" description="Example website" tag="more text"/>
```

What I want to get is `Example website`. Doing:

```
cat file | perl -pe 's/.*description=".*?"//'
```

works as expected, and I get `tag="more text"/>`, but when trying:

```
cat file | perl -pe 's/.*description="(.*)?"/\1/'
```

I get `Example website" tag="more text/>`, while I was expecting to get `Example website`. So it seems there’s something with the capturing and the backreference that is not working as intended, and although I think I might understand why, I’m not sure how to solve it.

I could always do:

```
cat file | perl -pe 's/.*description="//;s/".*//'
```

but I really want to understand how to solve it with the regular expression, instead of doing two substitutions.

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/perl for examples of how to properly parse HTML with Perl modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: I’m aware I shouldn’t try to parse HTML with regular expressions, but this is XML code gotten in response from an API call, so it not deviate, as it already contains only what I’m interested in. If the API response ever changes, so will my code have to adapt, but there won’t be any unforeseen cases that make regular expressions “dangerous” in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using non-greedy, you have greediness within an optional capture group as the question mark is right after the group's end parenthesis:

Change:

```
description="(.*)?"
```

to:

```
description="(.*?)"
```

and you should have your expected results.

Comment: I thought (and tried) about that, and it wasn’t working, I now realise why, I forgot to put the trailing `.*`, so it should be `cat file | perl -pe 's/.*description="(.*?)".*/\1/'`. I’ll still accept the answer, thank you.

Comment: The change in my answer is still necessary if you are hoping for your capture group to contain only the description value.

Answer (score 1):

The `?` metacharacter has two meanings in regular expressions.

When it follows a character like `*` or `+` which allows an expression to be matched a variable number of times, it is the "non-greedy" modifier.

```
.*?
a+?
(foo){3,}?               # actually, I'm not sure about this one
```

it
In other contexts, it means "match 0 or 1 times"

```
abc?d                    # matches "abcd" or "abd"
```

By putting the `?` outside the capture group, you have changed it to the second meaning. Put it inside the capture group, like @smerny said.

```
(.*?)
```